# Calibrating camera with custom principal point using OpenCV/C++(calibrateCamera)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0, camera-calibration

I'm trying to calibrate a camera with a principal point not at the center. Therefore, I set the principal point in the camera matrix as follows:

```
// Image size = 320 x 240;
Mat camera_matrix = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1, 0, 214, 0, 1, 106, 0, 0, 1);
```

To have the camera calibrated with the principal point fixed, I use the flag CV_CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT.

However, the documentation states that I need to use CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS as well to use my custom center:

```
CV_CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT: The principal point is not changed during the global optimization. 
It stays at the center or at a different location specified when CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS is set too.
```

When I using this flag, however, the camera matrix is not altered in any way; It is the same as before the calibration. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's how I'm using the flag with calibrateCamera

```
    // Set custom center by initializing camera matrix
    Mat camera_matrix = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1, 0, 214, 0, 1, 106, 0, 0, 1);
    .
    .
    .
    .
    double error = calibrateCamera(
        object_points,
        image_points,
        image_sz,
        camera_matrix,
        dist_matrix,
        rvec,
        tvec,
        CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT + CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS
    );
    .
    .
    .
    .
    // Getting undistortion maps
    initUndistortRectifyMap(
        camera_matrix, 
        dist_matrix, 
        identity, 
        camera_matrix, 
        image_sz, 
        CV_32FC1, 
        map1, 
        map2);

    // Correcting frame and displaying
    remap(test_image, output_im, map1, map2, INTER_LINEAR);
```

Comment: How do you use the flag? It'd be helpful if you shared a snippet of your code